# Giving input and output files for batch processing?

Tags: python, batch-processing

I have more than 100 .txt files in a directory, that I want to run the same python script for each one of the files. Right now I have to type a similar command over 100 times because there is a slight variation for each command because the input and output file names are different. I was wondering if this could done automatically.

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Excelseq ')
parser.add_argument('-i','--txt', help='Input file name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o','--output',help='output file name', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

df = pd.read_csv(args.txt, sep='\t' )
f=open('VD.fasta', "r+")
out = open(args.output, "w")

for line in f:
    title = line[1:]
    title = title.rstrip()

    seq = f.readline()
    seq = seq.rstrip()

    if  df['ReadID'].str.contains(title).any():
        out.write('>{0}\n{1}\n'.format(title,seq))
```

The code takes 1 input file: `df` which is given by `-i`, it is a .txt file, and the script checks if the `ReadID` from the .txt file is in the .fasta file. If it is, the script will print out the `title` and `seq`. But for each output file, I would like the name to be the same as the .txt file but with a .fasta extension.

For example:

```
input file1 : H100.txt
output file1: H100.fasta

input file2 : H101.txt
output file2: H101.fasta

input file3: H102.txt
output file3: H102.fasta

...
```

**How would I automate this for over 100 files? Each run takes a long time and I don't want to sit in front of the computer to wait for it to finish and then run the next.**

Comment: How is this related to [tag:batch-file]? Did you mean [tag:batch-processing] instead? Please read the tag infos and update your question accordingly...

Comment: @aschipfl done.. the batchfile tag was recommended so i used that.., actually the batchfile tag automatically updated my batch tag.. can't change it to just batch so i deleted it.

Comment: Since the name of the output file is related to that of the input file, just accept one argument—the input file's name—and have the script determine the name of the output file from that. i.e. just change the input file's extension.

Comment: ditto of martineau, briefly looking at your script it looks like you may being trying to do this with out.write('>{0}\n{1}\n'.format(title,seq)). if the issue is just changing the extension just use the [replace() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm).

Comment: You should change the extension using the `os.path.splitext()`function. Not the string `replace()` method.

Comment: how would i automate this for over 100 files? each run takes a long time and i don't want to sit in front of the computer to wait for it to finish and then run the next

Comment: Where do the names of the input files come from? Are they all in the same directory? Otherwise I don't see how a program could determine unless the user types them all in.

Comment: @ martineau yeah they are all in the same directory.

Comment: Just have your script accept one argument, the name of the directory the fasta files are in, and then use `glob.glob()` to get a list of all the `'H*.txt'` files in it. Then, for each one, determine the output file name automatically by changing the input file's extension, then perform the processing for that pair. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @martineau do you mind writing a solution ? i am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't test this because I don't have the input files nor do I have all the third party modules installed that you do. However it should be close to what you should do, as I was trying to explain in the comments.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import sys

def process_txt_file(txt_filename, f):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(txt_filename)
    fasta_filename = root + '.fasta'

    print('processing {} -> {}'.format(txt_filename, fasta_filename))

    df = pd.read_csv(txt_filename, sep='\t' )
    with open(fasta_filename, "w") as out:
        f.seek(0)  # rewind
        for line in f:
            title = line[1:].rstrip()
            seq = f.readline().rstrip()

            if  df['ReadID'].str.contains(title).any():
                out.write('>{0}\n{1}\n'.format(title, seq))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print('usage: {} <path-to-txt-files-directory>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(2)

    with open('VD.fasta', "r+") as f:
        for input_filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(sys.argv[1], 'H*.txt'):
            process_txt_file(input_filename, f)
```

Comment: the error says,  TypeError: splitext() missing 1 required positional arguments: 'p'

Comment: i modified the code to: root, ext = os.path.splitext(txt_filename)  , please change your answer so i can give you a check.

Comment: Oh, sorry, sure thing. Also note I also optimized the code to some degree as well. That could be taken even further by preprocessing the `'VD.fasta'` file into an in-memory list assuming it's not too big.